# Sort by Even and Odd numbers

Tags: c++, sorting, stdvector

I would like to know is it possible to sort number by even or odd using the std::sort function.

I have the following codes but i am not sure how to implement in the std::sort

```
inline bool isEven(const Point n) {
return n.getX()%2==0;
}
```

Is this correct

```
vector<Point> c;
std::sort(c.begin(),c.end(),isEven)
```

Please advice.

Comment: You want to sort only on X? Your code doesn't compile, you pass `n` then use `num`

Comment: a comparision function compares one thing to another, i.e. *two* things

Comment: Also, to test if a number is odd, use the `&` operator with 1 `(value & 1)` instead of doing a modulo (`%`) operation.

Comment: @emartel Why?  The only reason I can see is obfuscation.

Comment: @JamesKanze must be a question of habit but I don't find the bitwise AND to be obfuscating. Theoretically `& 1` should be more optimal than `% 2`. Even though Visual Studio will generate for both `mov byte ptr [isOdd],1` I wouldn't assume that every compiler will do it. Also, since we're talking about sorting, the speed of this operation should be considered critical.

Comment: @emartel how to implement & 1

Comment: @user1571494 `value % 2` will be 0 for even and 1 for odd, simply replacing `% 2` by `& 1` like in `value & 1` will be 0 for even and 1 for odd

Comment: @emartel You want to know if a number is even.  The definition of even is that it is divisible by 2.  Using bitwise operators to do this is lying about your intent.  And of course, every compiler today will generate exactly the same code for the two operations, so it really doesn't matter.  (In fact, in some cases, making your intent clear will help the compiler optimize.  I've definitely encountered the case where `h * 127` was faster than `(h << 7) - h`, on a machine which didn't have hardware division.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From what I understand of your question, you want to separate `odd` and `even` numbers. If that's the case, [`std::partition`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) will do just that.

If you want to sort by ascending values AND separate `odd` and `even` numbers, I would use something similar to this piece of code (still, you will have to figure out which component of your `Point` you want to sort on)

```
bool sortByEven(const int& left, const int& right)
{
    if(left & 1 && right & 1) // both are odd
    {
        return left < right;
    }
    else if(left & 1) // left is odd
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if(right & 1) // right is odd
    {
        return true;
    }

    // both are even
    return left < right;
}
```

This function can be used with [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort), here's a short example:

```
std::vector<int> numbers;
numbers.push_back(-1);
numbers.push_back(5);
numbers.push_back(12);
numbers.push_back(7);
numbers.push_back(-31);
numbers.push_back(-20);
numbers.push_back(0);
numbers.push_back(41);
numbers.push_back(16);

std::sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), sortByEven);
```

Will give you the following output:

```
-20 0 12 16 -31 -1 5 7 41
```

For other types simply change the `int` or make it a `template` parameter

Answer (score 5):

For this, you should use `std::partition` instead of `std::sort`

```
vector<Point> c;
std::partition(c.begin(),c.end(),isEven)
```

With sorting, you typically want the sorting to be based on the relative order of any *two elements*. In this case, you just want to partition your input based on an inherent property of your elements. Both cases can be reduced to the other, but it is always a little easier to take the direct approach.

Comment: will it sort the the elements with even value at the top and odd values at the bottom.

Comment: This will put all even elements in front of the odd ones, but you can just invert the predicate or use reverse iterators if you want it the other way around.

Comment: Than the isEven method is the same as I typed above or is it c++ method

Comment: The function you have above will work. I don't know what you mean by "C++ method"..

Answer (score 1):

If you look at a  reference for [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) you will see that the function it uses to compare should take *two* arguments that it should compare. So your code will not work at all.

I recommend you instead iterate over the vector, sorting out even values into one temporary vector, and the odd values into another temporary vector. Then you clear the actual vector, and append the two temporary vectors in the order you like.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a comparison function like

```
bool evenOddLess( Point const& a, Point const& b )
{ return (isEven( a ) < isEven( b )); }
```

Then you can use that as third argument to `std::sort`.

Answer (score 0):

In C# it is even simpler:

```
 class Program 
    {
        static void Main()
        {
          int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14 };

         //using delegate
          Array.Sort (numbers, (x, y) => x % 2 == y % 2 ? 0 : x % 2 == 1 ? -1 : 1);

          Array.ForEach(numbers, x => Console.Write(x));
          Console.WriteLine("");

         //using custom comparer
          CustomComparer comparer = new CustomComparer();
          Array.Sort(numbers, comparer);
          Array.ForEach(numbers, x => Console.Write(x));
          Console.WriteLine("");

          //using lambda
          int[] items = numbers.OrderBy(x => x % 2 == 0).ThenBy(x => x % 2).ToArray();

          Console.WriteLine("");
          Array.ForEach(items, x => Console.Write(x));
        }

        public int Compare(int x, int y)
        {
            return x % 2 == y % 2 ? 0 : x % 2 == 1 ? -1 : 1;
        }
    }

    public class CustomComparer : IComparer<int>
    {
        int IComparer<int>.Compare(int x, int y)
        {
            return x % 2 == y % 2 ? 0 : x % 2 == 1 ? -1 : 1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The catch is that there are two functions you can use.

```cpp
template< class BidirectionalIterator, class UnaryPredicate >
BidirectionalIterator partition( BidirectionalIterator first, BidirectionalIterator last, UnaryPredicate p );

template< class BidirectionalIterator, class UnaryPredicate >
BidirectionalIterator stable_partition( BidirectionalIterator first, BidirectionalIterator last, UnaryPredicate p );
```

> The functions [partition()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/partition/?kw=partition) and [stable_partition()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/stable_partition/) reorganize
>   elements of the collection in such a way that **all** elements for
>   which predicate p returns ***true*** will **precede** all those for
>   which p returns ***false***. It means that the elements will be
>   divided into two ranges:
>
> • [first, return_value)
>
> • [return_value, last)
>
> where `return_value` is the iterator returned by either of functions.
>   The sequence of elements in the resulting groups is where
>   `partition()` and `stable_partition()` differ.
>
> `partition()` **does not guarantee** any particular order within the
>   ranges.
>
> `stable_partition()` **will keep a relative order** of elements before
>   the split. It means that if there are two elements a and b, and a
>   precedes b, and if they both belong to the same group after the split,
>   element a will still precede element b.

Here is a sample code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

bool IsOdd(int i) {
    return (i & 1); //use !(i & 1); if you want to place even elements first in the vector
}

int main() {
    vector<int> v;
    // set some values and shuffle them:
    for (int i = 1; i<10; ++i)
        v.push_back(i);
    random_shuffle(v.begin(), v.end());

    cout << "All elements:";
    for (vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
        cout << ' ' << *it;
    cout << endl;

    //sort the vector
    cout << "Sorted vector:";
    sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    for (vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
        cout << ' ' << *it;
    cout << endl;

    //change to partition and see the difference
    vector<int>::iterator bound = stable_partition(v.begin(), v.end(), IsOdd);

    // print content:
    cout << "odd elements:";
    for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != bound; ++it)
        cout << ' ' << *it;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "even elements:";
    for (vector<int>::iterator it = bound; it != v.end(); ++it)
        cout << ' ' << *it;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Sorted odd-even vector:";
    for (vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
        cout << ' ' << *it;
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```cpp
All elements: 5 6 2 1 9 4 7 8 3
Sorted vector: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
odd elements: 1 3 5 7 9
even elements: 2 4 6 8
Sorted odd-even vector: 1 3 5 7 9 2 4 6 8
```

I hope it helps for understanding.