# Split Parity Function ordering odds and evens

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I've been staring at this and I can't figure out what i'm doing wrong.  I'm trying to write a function that reorders odd to be in front of evens in the array.  The inner order of odds and evens is not important meaning [3, 1, 4, 2] or [1, 3, 2, 4] are both acceptable.

Currently if I initialize `int arr[5] = {3,6,4,1,12}` I get an output of 3,4,1,6,2  Struggling to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Code below:

```
void SplitParity(int arr[], int arrSize)
{
    int tempValueHolder;

    for (int indexCounter = 0; indexCounter < arrSize; indexCounter++)
    {
        //Iterate through each index checking for odd
        if (arr[indexCounter] % 2 == 0)
        {
            tempValueHolder = arr[indexCounter];

            //If Odd.....shift all indexes forward and move current to the back
            for (int innerCounter = indexCounter; innerCounter < arrSize; innerCounter++)
                arr[innerCounter] = arr[innerCounter + 1];

            arr[arrSize - 1] = tempValueHolder;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort by Even and Odd numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416712/sort-by-even-and-odd-numbers)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot that after shifting everything, you must look at `indexCounter` once again (you don't know if the value that arrived in the first iteration of the loop when you did `arr[indexCounter] = arr[indexCounter+ 1];` is correct or not)

Simplest fix is to add `indexCounter --;` just after `arr[arrSize - 1] = tempValueHolder;`

It's also incredibly innefficient and I suggest you look at std::partition

Answer (score 0):

Use standard algorithms with the correct custom comparison function:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

template<class T>
bool is_odd(const T& value)
{
    if (value & 1)
        return true;
    return false;
}

struct odd_first
{
    template<class T>
    bool operator()(const T& l, const T& r) const {
        if (is_odd(l))
        {
            if (is_odd(r))
                return false;
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
};



int main()
{
    int vals[] = { 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0 };

    std::sort(std::begin(vals), std::end(vals), odd_first());
    std::copy(std::begin(vals), std::end(vals), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

expected output:

```
5, 7, 9, 1, 3, 6, 8, 2, 4, 0,
```

As per Fezvez's suggestion, std::partition:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

struct is_odd
{
    template<class T>
    bool operator()(const T& value) const
    {
        if (value & 1)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int vals[] = { 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0 };

    std::partition(std::begin(vals), std::end(vals), is_odd());
    std::copy(std::begin(vals), std::end(vals), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this much, much easier with [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort): [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/49425e19b9404547)

```
std::sort(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), [](int lhs, int rhs){
    return (lhs % 2 == 1 && rhs % 2 == 0);
});
```

Output:

```
3 1 6 4 12
```

---

Or, if you desire internal sorting within odd and even: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8be3549bb9b26893)

```
std::sort(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), [](int lhs, int rhs){
        int l_res = lhs % 2;
        int r_res = rhs % 2;
        if (l_res == r_res)
            return lhs < rhs;
        return (l_res == 1 && r_res == 0);
    });
```

Output:

```
1 3 4 6 12
```